# How to mask sensitive fields like passwords in JSON test in Scala?

Tags: json, regex, scala, data-masking

So this feels like an interview question but it's not. Before you mark this as duplicate, please know I've looked at other answers: 1. there's no scala solution, 2. my case needs a way to mask more than one matched key.

I have a def that makes all my http requests. After I send the request, I log the request and response. Since these requests have a JSON body that may or may not have a sensitive field like these:

```
challengeAnswer
currPassword
password
answer
oldPassword
```

I'd like to create a universal JSON scanner that DEEP scans the keys of a given JSON object and masks the value if it matches one of these regexes case insensitively:

```
.*answer.*
.*password.*
```

Sample Request Body:

```
{
    "resetPassQuestion1": "I pity the ...?",
    "resetPassAnswer1": "Foo",
    "resetPassQuestion2": "Let's grab a pint at the ...?",
    "resetPassAnswer2": "Bar",
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "loginId": "jdoe666",
    "password": "Secret1"
}
```

I need to mask Foo, Bar, and Secret1 in this example with 5 asterisks such when I print in the logs, it will print:

```
{
    "resetPassQuestion1": "I pity the ...?",
    "resetPassAnswer1": "*****",
    "resetPassQuestion2": "Let's grab a pint at the ...?",
    "resetPassAnswer2": "*****",
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "loginId": "jdoe666",
    "password": "*****"
}
```

I am not finding examples of case match that's insensitive. What's a good clear way to tackling this problem with easy to read code.

Comment: Are jsons just strings or are you using any library?

Comment: I am using LiftJson 2.10

Comment: Can you also share case classes, if you have any?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it using LiftJson's transform.

```
import net.liftweb.json.JsonParser
import net.liftweb.json.Printer.compact
import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._

private def maskPasswords(jsonStr: String): String = {
    Try(JsonParser.parse(jsonStr)) match {
        case Success(json) => {
            compact(
                render(
                    json.transform {
                        case JField("password",_) => JString("*****")
                        case JField("oldPassword",_) => JString("*****")
                        case JField("resetPassAnswer2",_) => JString("*****")
                        case JField("resetPassAnswer1",_) => JString("*****")
                    }
                )
            )
        }
        case _ => "**** JsonParsing Failed! **** Masking Everything *****"
    }
}
```

It's not perfect since every new field that I want to mask, I would have to add a new line here but it works well enough for me for now.